# How to change java sources directory in Gradle build script

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a project where the Java sources are not in the standard position Gradle expects them.

How can I point Gradle to the right directory ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no sources in `src/main/java` then it's slightly more correct to do

```
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['path/to/your/java/packages']
```

Comment: Yours is calling the [srcDirs(Object ...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html#srcDirs-java.lang.Object...-) method which adds to the existing srcDirs, mine is calling [setSrcDirs(Object...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html#srcDirs-java.lang.Object...-) which overrides the default config. With your version you have now configured two source directories (yours and `src/main/java`)